# Unity (URP) - mixed/rt shadows but only for dynamic objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting, urp

I am still new to unity, creating a project right now using URP (incl. bakery) and looking for a way to use lights and shadows in a way that may or may not exist ^^

I have a scene with mixed lights, having baked GI and shadowmasks, and combined with the rt-part of the mixed light the scene looks beautiful. Now I want to have dynamic objects (enemies etc. pretty much everything not static) to cast shadows from these mixed lights, which they do ... but I am not seeing a way to have "only" dynamic objects cast shadows. As it stands, everything is casting shadows, including staic objects that really dont need them due to the baked shadowmask - in fact, since my rt-shadows are very low res, the shadows look worse since these rt-shadows are stacked over the sharp baked shadowmask ones.

Well I am not an expert (far from it XD )... but aside from looking bad, I would assume having everything in a scene cast rt-shadows should be more performance heavy than just having dynamic objects cast shadows.

How can I setup my project to have mixed light only cast shadows for dynamic objects?

Thanks in advance,
ANB_Seth

Answer (score 0):

You probably have "Distance Shadowmask" enabled, which uses realtime lighting for all objects within a certain distance. If you switch to plain Shadowmask in the project quality settings then you will always use the shadowmask for static objects.